# MacBook Pro heat problem

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

My MacBook Pro 13" fell down from a coffee table and its getting heated up after that. Although the laptop is working with no problem of memory or hard drive, sometimes it makes a strange noise and gets hot pretty quickly.

Can I analyze/fix this issue myself or do I need to contact Apple Support (and if the later, would this be free)?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the fall may have damaged the fan. That would account for the heat and the noise. It's also possible the heatsink got slightly dislodged, which would also cause heat issues (although likely more severe).

In any event, unless it's clearly an unrelated problem (like a firmware or software bug), this damage is almost certainly not covered by Apple's warranty, as it's the result of an accident, not a part failure. However, from time to time Apple has been known to waive the repair charges on incidents that fall outside warranty coverage, although it seems to be on a case by case basis, and only with a bit of luck.

Comment: In addition, unless it's one of the most recent retina versions, Macbook Pros are fairly user-serviceable. [iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/) has replacement guides for Mac fans and heatsinks, and you can probably use one of those to at least re-seat the heatsink if it's come loose, or even obtain and replace the mechanism entirely.